# node formidable rename directory path from form fields

Tags: node.js, formidable

I need to set the file upload path based on form field values in a formidable form upload that has both the file and fields ( multipart form type).

theForm.on('fileBegin', function (name, file){ ...}
is called before
theForm.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) { ... }

However, it seems that the form upload path must be set before the form fields are parsed.  And so I don't see a way to access properties in  fields yet.  Theres nothing there yet except for prototype.  I also looked in req.body but the values aren't there either.

Is this correct?  Is there a way to change the form upload path after the form fields are available, but before the file is then saved to disk?

I am using the most current of everything as of today, 7/31/2017.

I also have body-parser in use, to read in JSON..  Could that be causing this issue? ( I've read that it is and also is NOT okay to use it- removing it causes other issues for me, so I've left it in so far .. )
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the [express-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) module:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
app.use(fileUpload());

var defaultDir = "C:\\temp";
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

    // The name of the input field (i.e. "clientfile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file 
    let sampleFile = req.files.clientfile;

    var savefile_path = path.join(defaultDir, req.body.path, sampleFile.name);

    // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server 
    sampleFile.mv(savefile_path, function(err) {
        if (err)
        {
            return res.status(500).send(err);
        }
    });
    res.status(200).send("File uploaded");
    console.log("File uploaded");
});
```